# Responsive icon on i3wm

Tags: icons

I have migrated from `debian` to `Arch`.
After installing my prefered apps, I've found, that there is no icon on bottom of `i3bar`, like `skype` or `Telegram`.

On `debian` I didn't do a thing except installing `i3wm`.

How to add this icons on `Arch` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to comment default

```
{
         status_command i3status
 #        tray_output primary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe install i3status and configure it in ~/.i3/config

```
 bar {
         status_command i3status
         position top
 }
```